# color significance for locked page in CME

Tags: cme

In CME there are few pages which are locked by person. Those items are appering in different colors:
1. One is using normal Page color with small lock.
2. Second one is having ligh grey color with small lock.

Anyone could explain me the different colors significance used by Tridion here.

[image: screenshot for reference]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That grayed out page has never been checked in, and this different color is used to show that if the author decides to cancel their changes the page will be deleted. If the changes to the other pages get cancelled, then they will revert to the previously checked in version, but for a new page that's impossible :)

Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: if the page was never checked in, then how can it be published (the blue publish icon is there on the page)? since only major versions are published and to create a major version, the page needs to be checked in first.

Comment: You can publish minor versions - either through workflow or in the UI. You won't be able to cancel your changes until it is unpublished though.

Comment: I tried creating a new page which has not been checked in (no major versions created) there is only a minor version and publish option is greyed out in CME/UI. I am the system admin. Only post I checkin the page (which creates a major version) I saw the publishing option enabled. Did I miss anything? I can create a different question specifically for the minor version publish if you want to provide a detailed answer on how to use the feature :) TBH, I was completely unaware that we can use minor version for publishing or any other activity for that matter since they are WIP

Comment: I'll have to double check _when_ it's possible, but it definitely is. If this wasn't the case you would never be able to create a new page with Experience Manager... Might be allowed via API only. Do open a new question, it's an interesting one.

Comment: The main reason for showing the page (greyed out) is to make sure when somebody tries to create a Page with the same name, the message "an items is already available with the same name" doesn't come as a surprise to the user, since they can see there is a page being created with that name already.